# Can't run snap apps on manjaro 'cannot open /proc/self/cgroup: Permission denied'

Tags: browser, opera, permission-denied, manjaro, snap

Recently I tried to run opera but nothing happened. So I tried to run it on terminal and got this error

```
cannot open /proc/self/cgroup: Permission denied
```

But I tried other snap apps such as code, it works fine,
and also recently saw a forum post that someone has the same problem with another browser.
Is it to do with the latest snap update on Manjaro? Or how do I fix it

Comment: Same problem here on Ubuntu after upgrade to 21.10.

Answer (score 0):

I was also experiencing this issue yesterday. My Plex went down during the day and I wasn't sure why. I found the error you posted when running:

```
sudo snap logs plexmediaserver
```

Rebooting my whole server fixed the issue.

Comment: Did not help in my case.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu `sudo dpkg-reconfigure apparmor` solved my problem.

From [this askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1369957/594043). Perhaps it's worth a try, even on manjaro.